# DRYing code in iOS / Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Are there any tools to detect repetitive code in iOS / Objective-C apps?

Comment: Command F? Not sure exactly what you are asking - Within the source code or during runtime?

Comment: In my surfing I have not come across any such tool for Objective C. It may be out there, I just have not found it yet. Definitely would be handy as several projects I've seen could hugely benefit :-)

Comment: @HotLicks Repetitive is not the same as copied. Terminology, man! ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) and [PMD's Copy Paste Detector (CPD)](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/cpd.html) to find duplicate code in your objective C source code. See instructions here: http://deadmeta4.com/2011/05/17/objective-c-copy-paste-detection-using-jenkins/

Answer (score 10):

[Here's a ZIP of a project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45054714/CPDObjective-C.zip) that uses same approach (PMD's CPD) and shows the results in Xcode's build log.

[image]

Comment: This is slick - any idea who created this?

Comment: Created what? :) PMD/CPD was developed by InfoEther. I took CPD's Objective-C Grammar from deadmeta4.com, and likend it to Xcode Project

Comment: I was wondering who wrapped it up into an Xcode project. Great work - thanks for sharing :)

Comment: @ReedOlsen - the wrapper might be the author of this non-english blog http://habrahabr.ru/post/137875/ ... somewhat translateable using http://itools.com/tool/google-translate-web-page-translator

Comment: Yeah, that post is mine also.

Comment: This is really cool but, when you try to do it with an iOS app, whose product is an executable like a mac os app, the run script doesn't work. Do you know any way to make it work with an iOS app?

Comment: Hello, this proj for MacOS, can you please give a sample with iOS target?